# How to add a value to an NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsorderedset

I'm using a NSOrderedSet to store the data in a Json server and do it that way because data arrives duplicated and I have to filter them to keep only one value. Now I need to add a value at the beginning of NSOrderedSet. I know how to add value to an NSArray, but not how to pass data from NSOrderedSet to the NSArray.

This is an example of what I get from the server:

```
{(
    AMAZONAS,
    AMAZONAS,
    ANTIOQUIA,
    ANTIOQUIA,
    ARAUCA,
    "AREA EN LITIGIO",
    "AREA EN LITIGIO",
    ATLANTICO,
)}
```

with NSOrderedSet sorts the data to avoid repeated as follows:

```
    deptoArray=[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:[_data valueForKey:@"Nombre"]];

{(
    AMAZONAS,
    ANTIOQUIA,
    ARAUCA,
    "AREA EN LITIGIO",
    ATLANTICO,
)}
```

but now I need to add a data at the beginning so that it is as follows:

```
{(
    Seleccione,
    AMAZONAS,
    ANTIOQUIA,
    ARAUCA,
    "AREA EN LITIGIO",
    ATLANTICO,
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard foundation collection classes are all immutable. So you need to create a mutable version of the collection. Either create it as a mutable ordered set

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *deptoArray = nil;
// ...
deptoArray= [NSMutableOrderedSet 
                 orderedSetWithArray:[_data valueForKey:@"Nombre"]];
[deptoArray insertObject:@"Seleccione" atIndex:0];
```

or create a mutable copy of the ordered set (skip `autorelease` if you use ARC)

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *mutableDeptoArray = 
            [[deptoArray mutableCopy] autorelease];
[mutableDeptoArray insertObject:@"Seleccione" atIndex:0];
```